# Access a list inside another list

Tags: c#

I have the following lists inside a class:

```
public class TriggerRequest
{
    public int requestReference { get; set; }
    public List<RequestParameters> requestParameters { get; set; }
    public List<RequestData> data { get; set; }
}
public class RequestParameters
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
public class RequestData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to access the "name" string from the class RequestParameters. I have tried using this:

```
TriggerRequest triggerRequest = null;
Console.WriteLine(triggerRequest.requestParameters.name);
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get the name from the requestParameters?

Comment: `requestParameters` is a `List`. You must first get an item to get to the `name` property

Comment: You'd need to tell it which item in the `RequestParameters` list you want to take the name from, so something like `triggerRequest.requestParameters[0].name` or `triggerRequest.requestParameters.First().name`

Comment: Since it's a list, you have to iterate the items and get value of name. Iteration does not require if you need the first name value, get it like @Equalsk suggested.

Comment: And btw, if `triggerRequest ` is null, you are not going to be able to access anything...

Comment: @Pikoh I know. I just typed it like that so the readers can understand what I am trying to do. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to tell it which item in the list you want the name of

e.g.

`triggerRequest.requestParameters[0].name`

or

`triggerRequest.requestParameters.First().name`

Comment: Will mark this as an answer because it was the first. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let the object of the class `TriggerRequest` be `objTriggerRequest` then `objTriggerRequest.requestParameters` will be a `List<RequestParameters>` So you have to access its `index` or else some LINQ extension methods to get each `RequestParameters` object from that. 
You can try something like this:

```
if(objTriggerRequest.requestParameters.Count > 0)
{
    string name = objTriggerRequest.requestParameters[0].name;
    // You will get the name of first RequestParameters object 
    // proceed with that
}
```

You can try using `First()` to get the first element, use loop if you need to iterate over the collection of `requestParameters`

Answer (score 0):

You can get one by one name of request

```
TriggerRequest trigger=new TriggerRequest();    
foreach(RequestParameters request in trigger.requestParameters)
{
   Console.WriteLine(request.name);
}
```

You can get specific request name by indexing it

```
 TriggerRequest trigger=new TriggerRequest();
 trigger.requestParameters[0].name
```